# Unity gameobject colour change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been with this for a while now, and am completly stuck. How exactly can I change of the colour of a game object when it is hit by another. What I want to do is when a target is hit, for it to change colour. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What part of the solution is causing you difficulty? If you post your example then we can better show where you are going wrong :)

Comment: Please be more specific as to the issue, but in general, use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html to detect collisions, and use the color property of https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html to change the color of an object.

Answer (score -2):

lets say you have a simple cube and you want to change the color of that cube on collission...
You can use

```
Getcomponent<meshrenderer>().material.color = color.red;
```

(or whatever you want)

Comment: You probably rather ment `GetComponent<Renderer>()` and `Color.red` ...

Comment: yes @derhugo thats exactly what im trying to say but some how it is not showing in the comment i dont know why .... when i try to edit the comment it appers in the edit box but not in  the comment

Comment: Well that was basically because you didn't format it as code. Stack overflow uses Markdown which then generates HTML content. Your `< >` where interpreted as Html tags ;) still .. your code wouldn't even compile .. there should be Capitalized letters

Comment: Thankyou for guidence @derhugo i'll consider these instructions next time :)